# add line break after certain amount of characters in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, line

I want to render some music data. I am saving the data i get back from an axios request into
an object called dailyPlaylist and destructure the values i need.

Since the artists and the name take a lot of space, i want to do a line break.

The artists come back as an array, so i could do:

artists: `track.artists.slice(0, 5).map(artist => <p>{artist.name}</p>)`

this works perfectly fine.

But now I am trying to do a line break also on the "name" property since some of the names are really long.
Is there an option to set a line break after a certain amount of characters?? I tried many methods I would use in vanilla JS but nothing worked.

For example i want to change the long name:

```
Dreamers (Music from the FIFA World Cup)
```

to:

```
Dreamers (Music from the <br>
FIFA World Cup)
```

or something like that.

My code so far:

```
 const dailyPlaylist = {

            tracks: response.data.tracks.items.map(({ track }) => ({
                key: track.id,
                name: track.album.name,
                artists: track.artists.slice(0, 5).map(artist => <p>{artist.name}</p>), // line break between artists
                image: track.album.images[1].url
            }))
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply limit the span name with CSS? Depending on the font it's nearly very hard to predict how many characters fit on a line, since each character is a different width.

Comment: You should definitely use CSS for that, and not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a good reason why you want to achieve this using Javascript, I would do it with CSS instead.
Limit the width of the div or span containing the title. You  could use max-width for example.

Something like this:

```
<span style={{maxWidth:100}} >
  <p>{artist.name}</p>
</span>
```